# external python shows up in anaconda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I am trying to follow this simple [tutorial](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#installing-a-different-version-of-python) to add different versions of python in anaconda. I do the following:

```
benjamins-mbp:ben ~ % conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda  
benjamins-mbp:ben ~ % conda activate py36  
(py36) benjamins-mbp:ben ~ % python --version  
>>> Python 3.8.2
```

I would expect `Python 3.6.10`

However, when I open a Jupyter notebook in the `py36` enviroment and check python, the version is correct:

```python
from platform import python_version
print(python_version()) 
>>> 3.6.10
```

I guess this happens because I created an alias in `.zshrc` ?

```
# Set alias for python3.8
alias python='python3.8'
```

`(py36) benjamins-mbp:ben ~ % which python` gives me `python: aliased to python3.8`

Why can I access `python3.8` from `py36` where it's not installed? How can I fix this so my virtual environment references its native python?

Comment: Get rid of the alias. The virtual environment is trying its best but it can't override an alias. Jupyter doesn't load your shell's rc file, so isn't affected by aliases

Comment: What does `which python3.8` show?

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You practically answered your own question. Shells tend to expand aliases before doing anything else. That's the whole point of an alias.

Normally, programs have one version on your system, so it's unlikely that something like `alias ls='ls -al'` or `alias rm='rm -i'` will trip you up. Python is special in that regard because it effectively encourages having multiple versions installed on your system (to say nothing of multiple copies of the same version) with virtual environments.

Virtual environments are configured through environment variables such as `PATH`. These don't play well with aliases. The solution is never to alias python. If you need to call it something else, make it a symlink in the `PATH` for the virtual environment you want.

This does not apply to the system install of python. Most likely, your scripts expect a particular version to be symlinked as `/usr/bin/python`. Your virtual environments should supersede the need for an alias at this point.